# MVC 4 and simplemembership, how to set password format?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am using MVC4 and simplemembership to create a web application.

Where or how do I set the password requirements? ie
- that the password needs to be a minimum 6 characters
- needs one alpha numeric
- needs one capital etc

I thought it was in the web config?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AccountsModels.cs` there is a class `RegisterModel`. You can annotate the properties there to add validation:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

For the specific requirements you can add a Regex that suits your needs with the `[RegularExpression]` annotation.